# To make a download functionality to download files from the server using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, download

I want to make a download functionality which has to download a file from the server using spring boot. 
The size limit of the file should be 1gb and I should have an option to download it as a zip file

Answer (score 0):

Hello to download any type of file you can use the following method. You must have configured the path before applying it.

```
 //descargar archivo
        @Secured({ "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER","ROLE_SADMIN","ROLE_USERGESTSERV"})
         @RequestMapping(value="/downloadFile/{filename:.+}")
            public void getLogFile(HttpSession session,HttpServletResponse response,@PathVariable String filename) throws Exception { 
             try {              
                    final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

                    Path pathFoto = getPath(filename);
                    log.info("pathFoto: " + pathFoto);
                    Resource recurso = new UrlResource(pathFoto.toUri());     
                    File fileToDownload = new File(pathFoto.toString());
                    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileToDownload);

                    response.setContentType("application/force-download");
                   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;recurso"); 
                IOUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
                    response.flushBuffer();
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception exception){
                    System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
                }

            }
```